# EWS Managed API and SQL Server - Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, ews-managed-api

I have a process that uses EWS Managed API to save email messages as eml files. Like this:

```
var propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead);
message.Load(propertySet);
File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, message.MimeContent.Content);
```

After the file is saved, I add a record to the database. The problem is, when the application is done saving the eml for *particularly large emails*, I cannot connect to SQL Server.  I get "**Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication**" when this code gets to here:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
     conn.Open();
```

None of the other posts with this error message seem to fit my situation.  I can connect to SQL Server with no problems until I run across a large email message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just keep your connection to SQL open while your process is running? Do you need to re-establish it for every message? If so - you will quickly run out of available ports or reach a user limit depending on how SQL Server is configured and your licensing model. You should do a `netstat` and check how the connections grow. Eventually these connections will be freed, but it is something to consider.

Are you using single or multi-threaded application model when interfacing and processing the EML files?

Comment: It is a single-threaded application running as a windows service. I had originally created new connections for each message because of the time it took to process each one.  I will try passing around one connection to each message instead.